# Converting dates from a database with nodejs javascript as to use in an html date input weird behaviour

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, format

Hope and appreciate to get some explanation for the following

The problem is about dates, and I know I could use a package like moments, though, in this situation I don't need to use dates that much. I also know that day and month obtained from respective Date get functions return a value which is one less then the actual corresponding value.

So, I have a form that saves data to a database and as for displaying saved data I need to convert dates to the format yyyy-mm-dd and for that I use a small function and the approach of separating date parts and rejoin them in proper order for the date picker.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3b9S.png)

The function used to format the dates (sorry for all the logs)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUV6g.png)

This function is called twice for each record, because there are two dates per record, and the console output is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t3Pl.png)

```
// the code for the function

export function dateToPug(dateIso) {

    console.log('\ndate string from db' , dateIso, '\n')
    
    const date = new Date(dateIso)
    
    console.log('toDateString',date.toDateString(), '\n')

    console.log('date string converted to date', date.toISOString(), '\n')
    
    const day = (date.getDate())// + 1)
    
    console.log('day extracted from date', day, '\n')
    
    // day < 10 ? day =`0${date.getDate()}` : ''
    
    const month = (date.getMonth())// + 1) 

    console.log('month extracted from date', month, '\n')

    // month < 10 ? `0${date.getMonth()}` : ''

    const year = date.getFullYear()

    console.log(`${year}-${month}-${day}`, '\n')

    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`

}
```

// the outupt

```
date string from db **1900**-**10**-**10**T00:00:00.000Z       // first date from the database record

toDateString Tue **Oct** **09** 1900        // converted to date string changes the day but not the month

date string converted to date **1900-10-10**T00:00:00.000Z    // date in iso format

day extracted from date **9**          // got day -1 as expected

month extracted from date **9**        // got month -1 as expected

**1900-9-9**     // date in format for the form input date (with trimmings that will have to be removed)


date string from db **1950**-**10**-**10**T00:00:00.000Z     // second date from the database record

toDateString Tue **Oct** **10** 1950    // converted to date string neither change the day nor the month

date string converted to date **1950-10-10**T00:00:00.000Z    // date in iso format

day extracted from date **10**          // got day unchanged

month extracted from date **9**         // got month -1 as expected

**1950-9-10**    // date in format for the form input date (with trimmings that will have to be removed)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Why do you try to re-invent the wheel? As mentioned in your question use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/), they do a perfect job!

Comment: Do you really store date like `**1900**-**10**-**10**T00:00:00.000Z`? This would be bad. In general you should **never** store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects. You can use above libraries to parse and convert the string values.

Comment: @Wernfried, I don't see right your points of view, text formatted was provided, I have stated I am not using dates that much that I feel I need to use a package, which I have used in other situation, date ate being stored as Date objects in mongodb docs. Sorry you wasted your time. For nothing. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how I managed to solve it, at least for know. On a later stage I eventually use a Library. But not for now.

```
export function dateToPug(dateIso) {

    const date = new Date(dateIso)
    
    let day = (date.getUTCDate())// + 1)
    day < 10 ? day =`0${day}` : ''
    
    let month = (date.getUTCMonth() + 1) 
    month < 10 ? month = `0${month}` : ''
    
    const year = date.getUTCFullYear()

    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not accounting for timezone differences.

I added this line to your function

```
 console.log('getTimezoneOffset',date.getTimezoneOffset())
```

and tested with node.js:

```
> dateToPug("1950-10-10T00:00:00.000Z")

date string from db 1950-10-10T00:00:00.000Z

toDateString Mon Oct 09 1950

getTimezoneOffset 300
date string converted to date 1950-10-10T00:00:00.000Z

day extracted from date 9

month extracted from date 9

1950-9-9

'1950-9-9'
```

`getDate()` returns 1-31, i.e. the actual day of the month, while `getMonth()` returns 0-11, i.e. month - 1, so this is correctly indicating month 9 day 9 for the noted timezone offset.

Note that 12:00 am on Oct 10 in London(UTC) is still Oct 9 for the entire western hemisphere.

The date functions default to using the local system timezone.  Depending on how you are running the code, you may need to explicitly specify a timezone setting to get that to behave the way you want.

Or just leverage the years of work by other people who have already worked on this problem, and use a datetime library.

Comment: thanks for added insight. Actually I managed to solve the issue with getUTC methods. (I would swear I posted a comment about it, but apparently I didn't :( ).
I am not using any library for this purpose because at this stage I want to keep dependency coupling as low as possible, for several reasons including, learning, testing, and eventually architectural issues.